Display only the record with zero value SQL query
Input table has following data:
            +--------+-----+
            |   Id   | set |
            +--------+-----+
            | ABC123 |   1 |
            | ABC123 |   0 |
            | ABC123 |   1 |
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | ZAC123 |   1 |
            | ZAC123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            | BBB123 |   1 |
            | BBB123 |   0 |
            | BBB123 |   1 |
            | BBB123 |   1 |
            +--------+-----+

Need result as below:
            +--------+-----+
            |   Id   | set |
            +--------+-----+
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | XYZ123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            | TNB123 |   0 |
            +--------+-----+

Query
Select * 
from X
where set='0'
having count(*)>1 

Not working as some are only one record as well

Try to avoid (a reserved words (like set) as a column name.

So if we had ID AAA123 with set 0, would you want to see it in results or not.  your last comment is ambiguous to me and your example data/expected doesn't include such  situation

This is one way:
select *
from my_table
where id not in (select id from my_table where my_table.set <> 0)

This will select all ids where set is not 0 in a subquery, then filter out those rows with a not in over the whole table.
https://dbfiddle.uk/QCPgxcK7 (Thanks @xQbert for the setup code)

Maybe i'm just missing something : https://dbfiddle.uk/Guls-AnE

@xQbert thanks, I forgot that "set" is a keyword. Works with x.set <> 0: https://dbfiddle.uk/QCPgxcK7.

Also I'm not sure why "set" <> 0 didn't work. It works in SQLite.

I'm confused by that as well.  Still unsure if we have record AAA123 with set value 0 if it should or should not be in the results with no other AAA123 IDs...   I think what you have is right but the last comment in the original question leaves me wondering.

sergey was close:
The issue here is you need to return all records and a group by given duplicate values will eliminate those.  So we need to first get a set of data which is for records where the set is all 0's and has a count > 1 then query the base set (x) for those records; returning all of them.
DEMO
WITH CTE as (select z.id
FROM x as z
GROUP BYz.id
HAVING min(z.set)=0 and max(z.set)=0 and count(*) > 1)

SELECT * 
FROM x 
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID 
             FROM CTE)

May not need the having count(*)>1 if you want records id's which only have 1 record with a set of 0.
Giving us:
+--------+-----+
|   ID   | set |
+--------+-----+
| XYZ123 |   0 |
| XYZ123 |   0 |
| XYZ123 |   0 |
| TNB123 |   0 |
| TNB123 |   0 |
| TNB123 |   0 |
+--------+-----+


Two other ways :
SELECT *
FROM x x1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM x x2
  WHERE x1.ID = x2.ID
  AND x2.set = 1
)

SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM x
  GROUP BY x.ID
  HAVING BIT_OR(x.set) = 0
)


Use SUM() window function to sum all set values for each Id. Return the Id's where that sum is equal to 0.
select id, `set`
from
(
  select *, sum(`set`) over (partition by id) set_sum
  from x
) dt
where set_sum = 0

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/iIw7_VHz (Built on @Dogbert's, thanks!)
Note: If set can be negative, do
sum(abs(`set`))


select t.id
from your_table as t
group by t.id
having  min(t.set)=0 and max(t.set)=0


Close you need to count t.id and make sure it's > 0 too I think and wrap it in a subquery or use a 2nd cte.
